# One shot lambda for an event and binding exception

Tags: c#, .net, events, reflection, lambda

I tried to unsubscribe from a lambda within itself. I used the MethodInfo class for getting information about a lambda and the Delegate.CreateDelegate method for creating the same method as a lambda. So it works fine if a lambda created in one of the class methods that contains the event i use but doesn't work in another class method (binding exception).

Here's the code:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public event Action SomeEvent;
    public void OnSomeEvent()
    {
        if (SomeEvent != null)
        {
            SomeEvent();
        }
    }
    public TestClass()
    {
        //IT WORKS FINE!!!
        //SomeEvent += () =>
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine("OneShotLambda");
        //    MethodInfo methodInfo = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod() as MethodInfo;
        //    Action action = (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), this, methodInfo);
        //    SomeEvent -= action;
        //};
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass t = new TestClass();
        t.SomeEvent += () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OneShotLambda");
                MethodInfo methodInfo = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod() as MethodInfo;
                //GOT AN ERROR
                Action action = (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action), t, methodInfo);
                t.SomeEvent -= action;
            };
        t.OnSomeEvent();
        t.OnSomeEvent(); //MUST BE NO MESSAGE
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623658/single-shot-event-subscription

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work is that you pass in `t` as the second parameter to `CreateDelegate` when you should pass `null`. This is due to the fact that the method created for the lambda will be a static method. Otherwise it couldn't be used from the static `Main` method. And the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74x8f551.aspx) clearly states that you need to pass `null` for static methods.

Having said that, you would be better off doing it differently:

```
TestClass t = new TestClass();
Action eventHandler = null;
eventHandler = () =>
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("OneShotLambda");
                   t.SomeEvent -= eventHandler;
               }
t.SomeEvent += eventHandler;
```

This code is more readable and understandable and additionally performs better.

Comment: If I pass null then t.SomeEvent -= action doesn't remove the current lambda from the event and there's no exception either (very strange). So I will use your solution. Thanks.